# Auto Login to Moodle with my website Credentials

Tags: api, moodle

I have an user details stored in my web site database and Moodle database. I logged my website with that credentials , Moodle also auto login with that credentials is there any way? Or any Code is available?

Comment: You can have SSO based implementation at both portal that way you can have auto login. https://moodle.org/plugins/auth_saml2sso

Answer (score 1):

If you're handling credentials correctly (and Moodle does), you **DO NOT STORE THE ACTUAL PASSWORD!** Instead, you store a salted hash of the password.

When someone tries to log in, you salt and hash the attempted password using the same salt and hashing algorithm. This will give you the same result as the value in the database, and so instead of comparing passwords directly you now compare hash values. In this way your users are protected from having their passwords leaked if someone breaches your application.

**If you're not doing it this way on your own site, you're doing it *WRONG* and need to fix it ASAP.** This is big deal!

*Here's the thing:* the two web sites aren't necessarily using the same hashing algorithm, and **certainly** aren't using the same salt. Therefore the user credentials you have saved for your web site are **NOT** the same credentials saved in Moodle, even if all the users have the same password.

But what you're really asking about is SSO (single-sign-on). There are (safer!) ways to support this. SAML, CAS, Shibboleth, and OAuth come to mind, and Moodle definitely supports these. You can also have Shared (as opposed to Single) Sign-On, where both your app and Moodle use a third party such as AD or LDAP for identity verification, so the username/password credentials are the same but you still have to sign into both applications separately.

Unfortunately, you will need to build this into your own app, as well, and perhaps even add an additional authentication portal server to your organization to act as the trusted intermediary between each of these applications. There are a number or products you can use, including some that are open source or may already be included with other licensing, so you don't have to start from scratch or necessarily make an expensive purchase here.

The good news here is these products generally also put you into a good position to start supporting Multi-Factor Authentication, which is also an important feature to provide.